Access row item of Gtk.ListView
I need to add a custom class to some rows in a GtkListView widget so that I can change their background colour. Looking on the inspector, ListItem rows are instances of GtkListItemWidget, but I can't find anything in the docs or online regarding how to access these widgets.
I am using Gtk 4. Would anyone have any insights on how to access ListItem rows?

See if you can get your ListItem based on:

Zero-based index, see Gio.ListModel.get_object.
Selection, see Gtk.SingleSelection.get_selected_item.

Usually I get my row based on the current selection, for example in C-style:
GtkSelectionModel *model = gtk_column_view_get_model (GTK_COLUMN_VIEW (view));
GObject *selected_row = gtk_single_selection_get_selected_item (GTK_SINGLE_SELECTION (model));
// now use selected_row to get your data based on how you build your liststore model

